# How do I restrict domains for Silverlight NetTcp connections?

Tags: security, silverlight, tcp, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I'm hosting a clientaccesspolicy.xml for a locally hosted Silverlight component that communicates using TCP connections.  It works but I'm trying to tighten the permitted domains and I can't find documentation to indicate how to specify these restrictions for TCP connections.

Is this possible, and if it is how should I be specifying these restrictions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <socket-resource port="4502-4534" protocol="tcp" />
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Basics of the Security Policy System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#Anchor_0)

> One additional restriction on using the sockets classes is that the
>   destination port range that a network application is allowed to
>   connect to must be within the range of 4502-4534. These are the only
>   destination ports allowed by a connection from a Silverlight
>   application using sockets. If the target port is not within this port
>   range, the attempt to connect will fail. It is possible for a target
>   server to receive connections on a port from this restricted range and
>   redirect it to a different port (a well-known port, for example) if
>   this is needed to support a specific existing application protocol.

I would think that narrowing the range of ports would would limit the available tcp sockets. They show an [Example Policy File for Sockets here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#Anchor_4)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>
        <domain uri="file:///" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <socket-resource port="4502-4506" protocol="tcp" />
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Citing the following documentation from MS

[To use a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to allow cross-domain access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> To enable the service for access over TCP sockets, add
>   `<socket-resource port="4502" protocol="tcp" />` to the `<grant-to>`
>   element, where the `4502` is the port value where the service is hosted.

**Domain example**

This policy file accepts connections only from the domains and scheme specified. This policy file specifies specific request headers and specifies resources that can be accessed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="MyHeader, X-API-*">      
        <domain uri="http://electronics.fabrikam.com"/>
        <domain uri="http://books.fabrikam.com"/>
        <domain uri="http://contoso.com:8080"/>
      </allow-from>      
      <grant-to>      
        <socket-resource port="4502-4506" protocol="tcp" />
      </grant-to>      
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

For the above policy, the Silverlight HTTP applications listed below are allowed to have access to the listed ports:

```
http://electronics.fabrikam.com/sample/app.xap
http://books.fabrikam.com/web/sample/app.html
http://contoso.com:8080/sample/app.xap
```

For the above policy, the Silverlight applications listed below are not allowed to have access to the listed ports:

```
http://electronics.fabrikam.com:8080/sample/app.xap
http://electronics.fabrikam.com:8080/sample/app.xap
http://bar.com/sample/app.xaml
https://bar.com/sample/app.html
```

The following HTTP request headers can be sent (in addition to the Content-Type header that is always allowed):

```
MyHeader
all headers starting with X-API-
```

Resource [Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Use of `<domain uri="file:///" />` or variations on it doesn't seem to work either unfortunately, and neither does `<domain uri="net.tcp:///" />`.